# Programming a buffer using ATMEGA328

Tags: arduino, atmega

Im just learning how to use the Arduino, so i bought a Arduino UNO that comes with the ATMega328. And just to start learning i was thinking to use the controller as a buffer:

[image: Buffer]

How would be the code for that? What pins can i use for a RS232 signal?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: As an aside, the Uno and the Uno R3 are different in non-subtle ways, so be specific about which one you have.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... Sorry but.. What? What do you want to do?
If you just want to use it as a buffer you can do this

```
const int inputPin = 2;
const int outputPin = 1;
void setup() {
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(outputPin, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(outputPin, digitalRead(inputPin));
}
```

But this is absolutely useless.

If you want to start from the beginning start reading the examples provided with the IDE. Starting from the classic example (blink a led).

As for the RS232.. You can't connect to a RS232 signal (because the RS232 signal is a bipolar signal which can range from -15V to 15V). If you want you can convert the RS232 voltage levels to UART levels (0-5V) with an IC (the most famous one is the MAX232).

And then.. You can either connect it to the TX and RX pins (but doing so you exclude the USB port) or to two other pins and then use the SoftwareSerial library.

But usually people use the integrated USB-Serial converter on the board: when you connect the Arduino to the PC your computer detects a new serial port..